# Can't update SQL table

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters, sql-update

I need to change values in table Iepirkumi to values that are in textboxes. Debbugger shows no problems, but the code doesn't work.

```
    string connectionString = (@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=""C:\Users\Davis\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\dati.mdf"";Integrated Security=True");
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd =
            new SqlCommand("UPDATE Iepirkumi SET"+
                " [Pieg_Nos]='@Pieg_Nos',"+
                " [Prec_Nos]='@Prec_Nos',"+
                " [Daudzums]=@Daudzums,"+
                " [Pieg_dat]='@Piegdat',"+
                " [Statuss]='@Statuss',"+
                " [Preces_kods]=@Preces_kods,"+
                " [Pieg_kods]=@Pieg_kods WHERE [Id]=@Id", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value=rindex;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pieg_Nos",SqlDbType.NChar).Value=textBox3.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Prec_Nos", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Daudzums", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = textBox5.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pieg_dat", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Statuss", SqlDbType.NChar).Value= textBox6.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Preces_kods", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pieg_kods", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Dati saglabāti.");
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never executed the command. Before

```
    conn.Close();
```

put

```
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, a suggestion: don't just display `ex.Message`. Display `ex.ToString()` to display the full exception, including any Inner exceptions. That's especially important with `SqlException` as ther can be a lot of detail.